# how to put php asset inside background image url laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i just want to put the name of the slider image inside foreach loop and all of it is inside css "backgound:image:url()" i want to write the php code inside background-image like css

```
background-image: url({{url('sliderimages/'.$slider->slider)}});
```

it dosn't display images

i when i am using asset it didn't work i don't know why please help

here is my foreach blade code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 homebanner-holder"> 
      <!-- ========================================== SECTION – HERO ========================================= -->
      
      @foreach ($sliders as $slider)
          
      <div id="hero">
        <div id="owl-main" class="owl-carousel owl-inner-nav owl-ui-sm">
          <div class="item" style="background-image: url(asset('sliderimages/'$slider->slider));">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="caption bg-color vertical-center text-left">
                <div class="slider-header fadeInDown-1">{{$slider->title}}</div>
                <div class="big-text fadeInDown-1"> New Collections </div>
                <div class="excerpt fadeInDown-2 hidden-xs"> <span>{{$slider->description}}</span> </div>
                <div class="button-holder fadeInDown-3"> <a href="index.php?page=single-product" class="btn-lg btn btn-uppercase btn-primary shop-now-button">Shop Now</a> </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.caption --> 
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
          </div>
          <!-- /.item -->
        @endforeach
          

          <!-- /.item --> 
          
        </div>
        <!-- /.owl-carousel --> 
 </div>
```

Comment: background-image: url("/sliderimages/'.$slider->slider")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in public styles folder:

```
background-image: url("{{ asset('sliderimages/'.$slider->slider) }}");
```

in other pathes:

```
background-image: url("{{url('sliderimages/'.$slider->slider)}}");
```